# how to test a site structure or dom

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I tring to generate some test over a page

I wonder if exists some jquery tool or similar where you can check if DOM is correctly loaded. If this block exists, if that div have that class etc etc, maybe is some high but I want do an automatism that check certain syntax of my website.

I found test in postman but I cant check the DOM there.
if you know some info about some tool that do this please tell me.

thanks in advance
Emiliano

Comment: You can use Selenium web driver to test the elements. For performance you can use JMeter + Selenium tests.

Comment: I think that I need study more, do you have some link with a tutorial to do that to see if this is that I want

Comment: For Selenium head to http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/ and for JMeter head to http://jmeter.apache.org

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you. I will put it in the answer section. Thanks!

Comment: I need something more like check with jquery the structure of the document and check if some block of content or ads is missing but I don't see how check it with this. sorry @NaveenKumarNamachivayam but this is not that I need

Comment: I am not expert in jQuery :) Thanks.

Comment: no problem man, selenium is very interesting but I cant check the dom and see if that blocks exists or not. maybe another person know how can i fix my problem.